# How to use insert, update, delete query in sql at same time?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Just stuck up, how to use multiple query in single form to execute different query.

eg:

[image]
Like in image, Table 1 has records.

what i am doing is:

extract first 3 record from table 1 and show in a form (frontend) and when this process is gone..

i need at same time , this happens without refresh and without user data or any frontend disturbance.

Once this data view to user:

i need:

same time, those 3 records get copy to table 2 from table 1. like Roll_no and Name.

Then, remove those 3 records from table 1.

i am doing this to prevent duplicate data and something.

so any code will be helpful.

Comment: You need to use  SQL procedures (MYSQL/PGSQL/SQL server)

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Are you asking how to execute various statements in a single transaction ?

Comment: Focus on question and rephrase it. And cut your image.

Comment: Trasactional SQL will help.

Comment: my question is straight:  i need insert command execute to take 3 data from table and show in user form. 2nd :   i need next query copy those 3 record from table 1 to table 2. 3rd:  3rd query will simply remove those 3 record from table 1.

and this whole thing should not affect user form or processing.

now can anyone ?

Comment: @devilcrab you don't need to speak perfect English to get answers on stackoverflow I truly am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. I just hope I got it right in my answer

Comment: Yea sometimes it becomes tough to explain up somethings.. this is similar case.. :P

Comment: he wants to select data from table 1, display it on the screen (So SELECT) he then wants to insert that data into table 2 and delete it from table 1 so he'll need some kind of key reference in the middle to know which records to INSERT across and which to DELETE from table 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear, but it seems you are concerned about data integrity performing multiple queries. What you need is to use [transaction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_transaction) to group a set of commands toghether. This way either all commands will succeed or your database will not be affected by any of them.

Comment: @devilcrab that would depend on the database you use and the way you use it. I strongly recommend you research the topic as performing transactions is a very important part of databases.

Comment: hmm i am using MySQL, and PHP. and all 3 table are in same database.

Comment: Then I guess [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html) is the link you need. I don't think I can explain it in few sentences and as the matter is well documented, I believe it is better for you to read from the source.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! now i will get over it :)